# How to optimize oracle query from partitioned table?

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle10g, partitioning, date-arithmetic

I have a partitioned table by date (by days) and a local index on the fields (including date field). If I make a query:

> SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.fdate = '30.06.2011'

it is fulfilled quickly, but when I make

> SELECT * FROM table t WHERE EXTRACT(month from t.fdate) = 6 AND 
>   EXTRACT(year from t.fdate) = 2011

it is fulfilled approximately 200 seconds.

How to optimize this query? May be I need to create local index on EXTRACT(month from date) AND EXTRACT(year from date)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have an index on the date field, you should write your query in a way that this index can be used. This is not possible with the EXTRACT functions since Oracle must go through all data and compute the condition for each row to determine if it matches.

The date index can be used if you have a specific date or a range of dates. In your case, you're looking for a range of dates. So the query could be written as:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.FDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('1.6.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30.6.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY');
```

Comment: @Codo: I've ran into similar problems and I'm sure your answer would make such queries run faster.  But I would guess that the reason it improves performance is because it enables partition pruning, not because it allows an index to be used.

Comment: if I do the same query as your solution, but include HHMMSS (our time stamp may even go all the way to milliseconds in some of our data)  -- will we still benefit from the partition by day?

Comment: @fa1c0n3r: Yes, it works for greater precision as well. However, if you have millisecond precision then you will have to use a TIMESTAMP column (instead of a DATE column) which is more complex due to its use of timezones.

Comment: I see, okay, thanks for checking it out.  That is what I thought I was seeing, but just making sure it would still be an efficient solution, since the size was getting quite big and we want to shave all the query time...